# MPI - changing number of processes launched

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

I'm beginning with MPI. I wanted to try a classical "Hello, world" program, which will print number of every process too and a few other informations too. My program works, but I'm little confused about how **mpiexec** really works. The problem is, when I specify the number of processes, sometimes they just don't get launched. For example, I use this command:

```
mpiexec -np 4 ./hello
```

but only 2 or 3 processes get launched, not 4. This number of launched processes changes, so I'm really confused. Is the problem in my pc (I have only dualcore) or is this normal?

---

**hello.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(){
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    // Number of processes
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size );

    // Number of current process
    int process_id;
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process_id );

    // Processor name
    char processor_name[ MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME ];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name( processor_name, &name_len );

    printf("Hello! - sent from process %d running on processor %s.\n\
        Number of processes is %d.\n\
        Length of proc name is %d.\n\
        ***********************\n",
        process_id, processor_name, world_size, name_len);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My mistake was pretty silly. I was just missing **MPI_Finalize()** function before **return**.

---

### Correct code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(){
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    // Number of processes
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size );

    // Number of current process
    int process_id;
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process_id );

    // Processor name
    char processor_name[ MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME ];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name( processor_name, &name_len );

    printf("Hello! - sent from process %d running on processor %s.\n\
        Number of processes is %d.\n\
        Length of proc name is %d.\n\
        ***********************\n",
        process_id, processor_name, world_size, name_len);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```